# Object pointers acting strange

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

I have a static vector of SessionMenu pointers defined in SessionMenu.h as follows:

```
static vector<SessionMenu *> sessionMenus;
```

I have defined an accountType enum in the SessionMenu class, and initialise this variable in the constructor of the SessionMenu class.

In the entry point of my application, I add three objects to this vector as follows:

```
SessionMenu::sessionMenus.push_back(&StudentSessionMenu());
SessionMenu::sessionMenus.push_back(&TutorSessionMenu());
SessionMenu::sessionMenus.push_back(&AdministratorSessionMenu());
```

At this point, when I debug the SessionMenu::sessionMenus at this point, the pointers are valid and the value of the accountType variable is as expected.

However, later in my application when I iterate over the vector my pointers as so:

```
for (vector<SessionMenu *>::iterator menuIterator = sessionMenus.begin();
    menuIterator != sessionMenus.end(); ++menuIterator) {
        SessionMenu *currentMenu = *menuIterator;
        if(currentMenu->getAccountType() == accountType)
            return currentMenu;
}

return NULL;
```

The pointers seem to be pointing somewhere different.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StudentSessionMenu()` is a temporary. The pointers only appear to be valid, but they're not. By the time you inspect them, the memory is already gone. You no longer own it.

What's weird is that you don't get at least a warning when attempting to take the address of a variable. **Are your warnings turned on? Are you ignoring them?**

Either allocate the objects dynamically (`SessionMenu::sessionMenus.push_back(new StudentSessionMenu());`) or use a vector of smart pointers.